# Images and elements on page not adjusting correctly when zooming

Tags: css, web

I have constructed 2 diagrams explaining my issue; 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4gCq.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8T0LR.jpg
I am new to css. I'm basically just trying to get everything on my page to 'stay still' when zooming. However I am having problems with this, elements on my page are adjusting/moving really wierd while zooming. Here is a snippet of my code:

```
table{width:100px;
height:60px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
background-color:white;
color:white;
}

body{
background: url(background.png), black;
background-position:center; 
background-repeat:repeat-y;

color:white;
}

#bannerImage{
text-align:center;
position:relative;
top:-68px;
margin-left:0px;
padding:0px
p

}

#letters{
text-align:center;
position:relative;
top:-178px;

}

audio{                        //example of element moving wierdly
position:absolute;
left:1500px;


}
div { overflow-x: hidden; }
```

How do I postion things so that they stay still!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting images for better understanding...

Instead of left, make it right

```
audio{
position:absolute;
right:50px;
}
```

this will do :)

Edit : Fiddle for batter understanding

```
http://jsfiddle.net/MarmeeK/tsaB8/
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. It still does the same thing. I want the element to display right next to the "Content" text, and not move from that position. Using the code you gave me, the element slides to the very right of the page at all times.